# SQL Update/Insert with loop for $_GET

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using ajax scripts for most of my site's functionality. In order to update or insert a row in particular table i send the request with $_GET, then retrieve each value with

```
foreach ($_GET as $item => $value){
        $$item =addslashes($value);
    }
```

and then i have this SQL Statement for the query

```
if($_GET['action']=='update'){
     $sql =$conn->query("UPDATE `newDrivers` SET `idCompany`='$idCompany', ...
     WHERE `id`='$id'");
}
else{
     $sql =$conn->query("
    INSERT INTO `newDrivers`(`idCompany`, ...) 
    VALUES ('$idCompany', ...)");
}
```

I see inefficiency, naming each column and creating new file for each table i have. Is there any way i can update/insert without naming each column individually so the script would be more of a universal one?

Comment: a name/value pair table might be a simple solution.

Comment: PHP can read the column names of the database.  Is that what you are attempting to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's depends from your database adapter.
In your case you may write construction like this

```
$columnsForUpdate = array();
//collect array with all pair `field` = 'value'
foreach ($_GET as $item => $value){
  $value = addslashes($value);
  $columnsForUpdate[] = "`{$item}` = '{$value}'";
 }
 if($_GET['action']=='update'){
 //concat it to string
 $columns = implode(', ', $columnsForUpdate);
 $sql =$conn->query("UPDATE `newDrivers` SET {$columns} WHERE id = {$id}")
 }
else{
     $columns = implode(', ', $columnsForUpdate);
    //insert have SET syntax too
     $sql =$conn->query("INSERT INTO `newDrivers` SET {$columns}");
}
```

Comment: That looks nice, let me give it a try and tell you if it worked

Comment: Seems like this will save me tons of coding! Thank you!!